# Emulator shows a black Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2

I am Configuring Android studio on my server. Everything works fine except the emulator. When I run an emulator, It boots up showing Android logo. After that, Emulator screen goes black. 
I tried the following Troubleshooting steps

- Enabling VT-X in BIOS.
- Installing HAXM.
- Graphics acceleration to various settings 'Software','Hardware' & 'Automatic'
- Installing Intel x86 Atom System Image & Intel x86_64 Atom System Image from SDK manager.
- Changing Virtual machine RAM to 2GB & 3GB
- Updating latest avd manager and Android studio.

Unfortunately Nothing Works

My System details are:

- Windows server 2012 R2
- Xenon E5405 @2 Ghz
- 20 GB of RAM

Android studio Details

```
 Android Studio 3.0.1 Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
   JetBrains s.r.o Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3
```

VM details:

```
Name: Nexus_6_API_22  
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)  
Path: C:\Users\user2\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_22.avd  
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 22)  
Skin: 1440x2560  
SD Card: 1 GiB  
hw.dPad: no  
hw.lcd.height: 2560  
runtime.network.speed: full  
hw.accelerometer: yes  
hw.device.name: Nexus 6  
vm.heapSize: 256  
skin.dynamic: yes  
hw.device.manufacturer: Google  
hw.lcd.width: 1440  
hw.gps: yes  
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait  
skin.path.backup: _no_skin  
image.androidVersion.api: 22  
hw.audioInput: yes  
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\  
tag.id: google_apis  
showDeviceFrame: no  
hw.camera.back: none  
hw.mainKeys: no  
AvdId: Nexus_6_API_22  
hw.camera.front: none  
hw.lcd.density: 560  
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 6 API 22  
hw.gpu.mode: auto  
hw.device.hash2: MD5:984dbf66b1aaafcdb7e89573ffb74b46  
hw.ramSize: 3072  
hw.trackBall: no  
PlayStore.enabled: false  
fastboot.forceColdBoot: yes  
hw.battery: yes  
hw.cpu.ncore: 2  
hw.sdCard: no  
tag.display: Google APIs  
runtime.network.latency: none  
hw.keyboard: yes  
hw.sensors.proximity: yes  
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M  
hw.sensors.orientation: yes  
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8  
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Emulator takes time(sometimes several minutes depends on system) to up.

Comment: Have you tried updating Android Emulator from SDK tools? I faced a similar situation for Oreo emulator, but it was fully black screen without even showing android logo, fixed by updating.

Comment: @ZaidMirza I waited about 30 Mins. But nothing Shows Up

Comment: @AtulVasudevA I tried updating Android 5 & 6  SDK but no change :(

Comment: I have the same issue but only for Oreo.  Works for Marshmallow